# regex ruby in meta keywords with limit and special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this ruby regex for validate that the user enter meta keywords separated by commas.

```
validates_format_of :tags, :with => /^\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+(\s*,\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\s*$/u
```

I want add 2 conditions more to this regex:

- limit the keywords to 4 keywords.
- Add spanish characters like `ñáéíóú` with `p{L}\s\p{N}`

**How can add this 2 conditions to this regex?
Thank  you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I think this regex will do the trick.

```
/^(([^,]+),){0,3}([^,]+)$/
```

You can put your validation like this:

```
validates_format_of :tags, :with => /^(([^,]+),){0,3}([^,]+)$/
```

Or with the `validates` method

```
validates :tags, format: {with: /^(([^,]+),){0,3}([^,]+)$/}
```

Both will do the same

NOTE: You should check [Rubular](http://rubular.com), it is a great Ruby regex online editor

Comment: Thank you very much @rogeliog. your regex fix the first problem **limit the keywords to 4 keywords.** But I have a second problem with characters `ñáéíóú`. How can I add this characters? Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want all printable characters áéíóú*aãaä to be allowed? Like everything except the 'coma'? You can do it like this `/^(([^,]+),){0,3}([^,]+)$/`

Comment: Gread, I'm glad it worked. I have edited the answers just to display the new regex